# Sending an ajax request and updating a button status

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code for a button,

```
<table style='border:0;margin:0;padding:0;'><tr><td>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type='submit' id='ajaxwel'
class='".(getqrsitebooleans($companyqr,10002,'True') === 'True' ? 'togglebtn' :
'togglebtnon' )."' name='dotogglebool' value='".
(getqrsitebooleans($companyqr,10002,'True') === 'True' ? 'Skjul' : 'Vis' ).
"'><input type='hidden' name='mainsetup' value='1'><input type='hidden' 
name='itemid' value='10002'></form></td><td>$tmptextholder</td></tr></table>
```

what I want to do is send the form off with ajax and then update the buttons status, which is done by `class='".(getqrsitebooleans($companyqr,10002,'True') === 'True' ? 'togglebtn' : 'togglebtnon' )."'`

But currently I have no idea of how to do either. The button has two states that are changed by values in a database, when clicked it sends off a POST that changes the value in the database, reloads the site and then reads the change and shows the changed status as going from green to red,

I assume I will be using the $.ajax, but not completely sure. Any help would greately appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(function(){
  complete: function(){
     $('#ajaxwel').prop('val','Submit'); 
  },
  beforeSend: function(){
     $('#ajaxwel').prop('val','Sending..');
  }
});
```

Comment: could I ask you to explain your answer a bit more? How do I update the button form to registere the change in value? sorry my first attempt with ajax, so need some guidance through it to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
<?php
    echo "<table style='border:0;margin:0;padding:0;'><tr><td>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' id='ajaxwel'
           class='".(getqrsitebooleans($companyqr,10002,'True') === 'True' ? 
           'togglebtn' : 'togglebtnon' )."' 
           name='dotogglebool' value='".(getqrsitebooleans($companyqr,10002,'True') === 'True' ? 'Skjul' : 'Vis' )."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='mainsetup' value='1'><input type='hidden' name='itemid' value='10002'>
    </form></td><td>".$tmptextholder."</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, might not have made that clear, the code is inside the php tag but i'm trying to send it off without having to update the whole page again, sending the user away from the button that was clicked. But only update the actual button form to register the changed value.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX will call a page you created.  That page does all the DB pings.

Make sure you post the correct variables.  ALSO:  On that page, you will return Javascript, JSON, XML or whatever else is parsable... and parse it inside the complete function.  Inside that page, make sure all your operations are handled, and the database queries what you want.

Would you want me to post a sample page?  A sample call? etc?

Data:
Page being pinged:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tt3-8j2

the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({}
  method:"POST",
  data: {myItem: "some data"}
  url: "TESTPAGE.php",
  success: function(a,b,c){
    $("#button").val(JSON.parse(a.responseText)["out"]);
    //if something is updated you might want to disable it as well temporarily.
    $("#button").css("disabled","disabled");
  }
);
```

this will ping a page with the posted data.  You will do some db stuff, and echo a return.  The returned stuff is then passed into the success call.

I cant test it really atm, minor errors like which variable in success call, etc.

The button should have its value changed to "updated"

Comment: updated.   ALSO you will need to make sure the url dir is correct.  What do i mean?  I mean that TESTPAGE.php in my example would be in the same dir... but a lot of people segregate the information by putting webservices into different directories etc.

Comment: I think I understand how to send my request off, need to send name=dotogglebool value=itemid, but unsure as to how I refresh the button to show the new state that is triggered after sending the post?

Comment: you wouldnt need to refresh the page at all with AJAX.  it would allow your code to modify dynamically during client side run times..  I would reccomend you use your browsers JAVASCRIPT toolkit and 1) follow console errors and 2) follow the network, to see what errors return etc when the request is fired if any.